authenticate stackoverflow exception
when i do compilation of my code everythings fine, register working well, verifying too, but when i do post-mapping login, i got an infinite recursion with StackOverFlow exception
AuthenticationService:
public AuthenticationResponse login(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    request.getUsername(),
                    request.getPassword()
                )
        );
    
        var user = userRepository.findByUsername(request.getUsername())
                .orElseThrow();
    
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return AuthenticationResponse
                .builder()
                .accessToken(jwtToken)
                .build();
}

AuthenticationController:
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> login(
        @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest request)
{
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.login(request));
}

UserRepository:
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    boolean existsByUsername(String username);

    boolean existsByEmail(String email);

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}

exception:
2024-06-04T22:21:27.080+05:00 ERROR 19412 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ref.Reference.refersToImpl(Reference.java:384) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ref.Reference.refersTo(Reference.java:375) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.isAccessChecked(AccessibleObject.java:704) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.verifyAccess(AccessibleObject.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:713) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:571) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy123.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]

i tried to fix dependencies and jwts but the problem is inside AutnhenticationManager, because when i deleted it and put null it started working

Please post the full stacktrace, this looks like just a snippet. There is too little information here to answer this question. Add your security configured, the User in question etc.

i got the problem with stackoverflow in beans
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
    return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
}

}
solved it with
@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    return authProvider;
}

